# How to view individual images in photos app

Tags: photos

I changed iPhone's and with the new one the photos get imported successfully - as shown below. The weird thing is I can not get the images to display except in thumbnails. With the prior phone I would double click on an image and it would be shown in a large size view.

[image]

So what am I missing now in how to view the individual photos in larger resolution?

**Update** Found this Apple provided documentation https://support.apple.com/guide/photos/browse-and-view-photos-pht56eafa987/mac :

[image]

However double-clicking or pressing return just puts that blue check-mark: does *not*  work.

**Update** An answer mentioned to *import* the photos. Well they are already imported: I had double checked and even went into the `Library` on disk and was able to open the photo from there.. But that's a really awkward/long-ish process..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top right corner, you should see import photos button. Pressing it will import them. What you're seeing now is the preview and selection window where you choose which photos to import.

[image: Like this screenshot]

Comment: Updated the question to include info the photos were definitely _already_ imported.  But it _is_ interesting that the button to `Import All New Items` is enabled: it should not be.